# How to re-index 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Lets say we have a 3D array like:

`array = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2, 2)`
`new_array = np.zeros((2, 2, 2))`

and lets assume we have some new random x,y,z indices for our array

```
x,y,z = np.meshgrid(array, array, array)
```

What is the fastest way to re-index our array?

A simple solution given here:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    for y in range(0, 3):
        for z in range(0, 3):
            new_x = x_coord[x,y,z]
            new_y = y_coord[x,y,z]
            new_z = z_coord[x,y,z]

            new_array[x,y,z] = array[new_x, new_y, new_z]
```

Is there a `one-liner` for this that I am not aware of?

**EDIT**

Yes, there is... very easy:

```
vol = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2, 2)
arr = np.arange(2)
x,y,z = np.meshgrid(arr, arr, arr)


print(vol)
print(vol[y, x, z]) ### ---> You have to swap the axes here tho. Does anyone know why?

[[[0 1]
  [2 3]]

 [[4 5]
  [6 7]]]
[[[0 1]
  [2 3]]

 [[4 5]
  [6 7]]]
```

Also, it is very slow. Any ideas how to improve the performance?

Comment: Your example would be a lot better if it used integers for indexing and worked.

Comment: Fixed it for you! Better now? Or do you want me to give a proper example? I thought the idea should be quite simple? I do not know why there is no simple operation in numpy to do that as I think this is just a simple re-indexing task. @miradulo

Comment: Can you explain in words what you imagine your algorithm is doing?

Comment: `randint` will simplify the random value generation.

Comment: Have you tried `arr[xcord, ycord,zcord]`?

Comment: @hpaulj Given that each mask is the same size as the entire array, how would that work?

Comment: @mad, as long as they broadcast together it doesn't matter what the shape of 3 arrays is,

Comment: @hpaulj Okay, so basically what I want to do is change the indices of the values in my array. I just simplified the question, but actually I rotated a 3D volume / array. Lets say by 90 degrees, and now I want to set the values by having the `new indices`. Do you know what I mean or shall I make it 100% clear? I just wanted to keep this question as simplistic as possible since it could be applied to many different applications.

Comment: Evidently at the point you've only made yourself 50% clear, if that!

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
In [54]: arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [55]: x = np.random.randint(0,3,(3,3))
In [56]: y = np.random.randint(0,3,(3,3))
In [57]: x
Out[57]: 
array([[2, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])
In [58]: y
Out[58]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

The simplest application of these indexing arrays:

```
In [59]: arr[x,y]
Out[59]: 
array([[6, 0, 3],
       [0, 7, 4],
       [0, 1, 3]])
```

The iterative equivalent:

```
In [60]: out = np.empty_like(arr)
In [61]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     for j in range(3):
    ...:         out[i,j] = arr[x[i,j], y[i,j]]
    ...:         
In [62]: out
Out[62]: 
array([[6, 0, 3],
       [0, 7, 4],
       [0, 1, 3]])
```

Your code isn't the same, because it is modifying the source array as it iterates:

```
In [63]: arr1 = arr.copy()
In [64]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     for j in range(3):
    ...:         arr1[i,j] = arr1[x[i,j], y[i,j]]
    ...:         
In [65]: arr1
Out[65]: 
array([[6, 6, 3],
       [6, 7, 7],
       [6, 6, 6]])
```

There isn't a simple equivalent.

---

You can index with `arr[x_coord,y_coord,z_coord]` as long a indexing arrays broadcast together.  Where they all have the same shape that is trivial.

```
In [68]: x1 = np.random.randint(0,3,(2,4))
In [69]: x1
Out[69]: 
array([[2, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2]])
In [70]: arr[x1,x1]
Out[70]: 
array([[8, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 8]])
```

A simpler way of picking random values from an array is to create random row and column selectors, and use `ix_` to create arrays that broadcast together:

```
In [71]: x1 = np.random.randint(0,3,(3))
In [72]: y1 = np.random.randint(0,3,(3))

In [75]: np.ix_(x1,y1)
Out[75]: 
(array([[2],
        [1],
        [1]]), array([[2, 2, 1]]))
In [76]: arr[np.ix_(x1,y1)]
Out[76]: 
array([[8, 8, 7],
       [5, 5, 4],
       [5, 5, 4]])
```

---

Almost sounds like you just want to shuffle the values of the array, like:

```
In [95]: arr
Out[95]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [96]: np.random.shuffle(arr.ravel())
In [97]: arr
Out[97]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [7, 4, 3],
       [6, 5, 8]])
```

Comment: I just created a random array in order to make the input to my "problem" simpler. But in the end there will only be one index for another index in the end. So basically a permutation of values based on new transformed indices.

Comment: Anyways if the 3 coordinate arrays have the right values and shape, they can be used as I first indicated `arr[x, y, z]`.